# Firefox addon how to handle page scrolling

Tags: javascript, event-handling, firefox-addon, fennec, firefox-addon-restartless

I need to handle page scrolling in fennec addon
I did next thing:

```
function onScrollHand(window, event) {
 showToast(window, "Scrolling");
}

var windowListener = {
  onOpenWindow: function(aWindow) {
    let domWindow = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

    domWindow.addEventListener("onscroll", function onScroll(event) {
      onScrollHand(domWindow ,event);
    }, false);
  }, 
};

function startup(aData, aReason) {
  let wm = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);

  wm.addListener(windowListener);
}
```

And I didn't receive scrolling events.
Has someone any idea or some working code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by adding

```
window.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll (event) {
}
```

in function loadIntoWindow(window) function

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` does not use `on*`, i.e. it should be:

```
domWindow.addEventListener("scroll", function onScroll(event) {
  onScrollHand(domWindow, event);
}, false);
```

Overriding `window.onscroll` is problematic, to say the least, as it will override whatever `onscroll` a page has set itself. `addEventListener` does not override.